# Setting cookies with form input

Tags: javascript, forms, cookies

I am trying to make a username cookie using the user's input to a web form. However it's not working and I don't know why.  Do you know what the problem is?

```
<form>
    <input type="text" value="Enter Your Nickname" id="nameBox">
    <input type="button" value="Go!" id="submit" onClick="setCookie();">
<form>


<script>
    var today = new Date();
    var expiry = new Date(today.getTime() + 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000); // plus 30 days

    function setCookie(name, value){
        document.cookie=name + "=" + escape(value) + "; path=/; expires=" + expiry.toGMTString();
    }
    //this should set the UserName cookie to the proper value;
    function storeValues(form){
        setCookie("userName", form.submit.value);
        return true;
    }

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: There's no putCookie function in the javascript code; looks like you called it setCookie

Comment: fixed that it still doesn't work

Comment: is the `escape(value)` function defined? what is it returning

Comment: Why is your `script` outside of `body` and `head` inside `html`? That’s invalid markup. Also, did you define `form` and `submit`?

Comment: I've put the script in the body.Maybe I'm not checking for cookies right.

Comment: I can’t edit my comment any more but forget about the `form` and `submit` thing… Anyway, does the console give you any errors? Does [JSHint](http://jshint.com) help?

Comment: I've put the script in the body.Maybe I'm not checking for cookies right. I'm using a chrome extension to check for cookies and I

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check below code, it might help you.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
var today = new Date();
  var expiry = new Date(today.getTime() + 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000); // plus 30 days

  function setCookie(name, value)
  {
    document.cookie=name + "=" + escape(value) + "; path=/; expires=" + expiry.toGMTString();
  }
function putCookie(form)
                //this should set the UserName cookie to the proper value;
  {
   setCookie("userName", form[0].usrname.value);

    return true;
  }

  </script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
 <input type="text" value="Enter Your Nickname" id="nameBox" name='usrname'>
 <input type="button" value="Go!" id="submit" onclick="putCookie(document.getElementsByTagName('form'));">
</form>
</body>


</html>
```

While defined function name should be putCookies instead of storeValues and function call you can do this way:
putCookie(document.getElementsByTagName('form'));

Inside the function definition cookie values can be get from the form as below:
setCookie("userName", form[0].usrname.value);

Form element should have attribute : name='usrname'

It will surely set cookies for your username with form element.

Comment: I have just modified few attributes of the html elements, all others are your code only, to work it out @user4485835

Answer (score 0):

Change the form to:

```
<form onsubmit="storeValues(this)">
<input type="text" value="Enter Your Nickname" id="nameBox">
<input type="submit" value="Go!" id="submit">
<form>
```

And storeValues(form) function to:

```
{
   setCookie("userName", form.nameBox.value);
   return true;
}
```

Comment: And how do you connect them?