# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property cookie

Tags: javascript

I finally get the code to work after a search online I get the right solution to it at [Setting cookies with form input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419929/setting-cookies-with-form-input)

the code works but the value submitted are not what i expect.
it store this value="Submit!" but i want to store the value submited
How do i get the value submited

```js
var today = new Date();
var expiry = new Date(today.getTime() + 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000); // plus 30 days

function setCookie(name, value) {
  document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + "; path=/; expires=" + expiry.toGMTString();
}

function putCookie(form) {
  alert("Hash send sucessfull");
  setCookie("hashvalue", form.hashform.value);
  return true;
}

function storeValues(form) {
  setCookie("hashvalue", form.submit.value);
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form name='hashform' onsubmit="storeValues(this)">
  <input type="text" value="Enter Your hash to mine" id="usrname">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit!" id="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: The error says that `form[0].usrname` is undefined. Consider debugging to figure out why?

Comment: @evolutionxbox in fact i have try debug it and its sounds like the cause its because Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute i have try change my code but its seems i was not right about it

Comment: I believe you need to use form.elements to read the values for each. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements

Answer (score 0):

In fact last error was the name of the form in the line:

> setCookie("hashvalue", form.hashsandbox.value);
> i haved form.submit.value and need to have the name of the field

Here is the full working code

```js
var today = new Date();
var expiry = new Date(today.getTime() + 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000); // plus 30 days

function setCookie(name, value) {
  document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + "; path=/; expires=" + expiry.toGMTString();
}

function storeValues(form) {
  setCookie("hashvalue", form.hashsandbox.value);
  alert("Hash send sucessfull");
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form name='hashform' onsubmit="storeValues(this)">
  <input type="text" value="Enter Your hash to mine" id="hashsandbox">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit!" id="submit">
</form>
```